# How can I close workspace with vscode.commands.executeCommand?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In reference, there is no API to close Folder/Workspace.
https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/commands

Then, how can I close Folder/Workspace programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
    vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.closeFolder');
```